# How to construct an expandable dropdown using angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to construct an expandable dropdown using `angular2`. Upon `onClick` the dropdown would expand and `onBlur` dropdown would contract.

The only way I can think of to achieve this behavior is to keep a variable that keep track of the state.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  pipes: [SearchPipe],
  template: 
  `
  <div (blur)=updateState(false)>
      <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="name" (click)="updateState(true)>
      <li *ngIf="my_state" *ngFor="#item of items | search: searchText">
        <div>{{item.title}}</div>
      </li>
  </div>
  `
})
export class Dropdown {

    items = [{title: 'hello world'}, {title: 'hello 2'}, {title: 'foo bar'}];
    searchText = '';
    my_state = false;

    updateState(show_flag) {

        my_state = show_flag
    }
}
```

Having to update state make code a bit messy, is there a better way of achieving an expandable dropdown?

Comment: you want something like this (sidenav expanable menu) in angular2 https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better/simpler way of achieving this (Hopefully someone will correct me :) ). But you could make your variable local to the template only and get rid of the `updateState()` method.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <div>
      <input (blur)="my_state =false" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="name" (click)="my_state = true">
      <div *ngIf="my_state">
        <li *ngFor="#item of items">{{item.title}}</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    items = [{title: 'hello world'}, {title: 'hello 2'}, {title: 'foo bar'}];
    searchText = '';
}
```

[Plunker demonstrating both the above and below ways](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rrl3AMRoHOgRd2uQpfxa?p=preview)

An alternative way (not necessarily better way) involves creating a separate component for the dropdown menu and having a public method on it to change the state of the menu ( same logic just maybe cleaner code)

```
@Component({
  selector:'dropdown',
  template:`
    <div *ngIf="isOpened">
      <li *ngFor="#item of items">{{item.title}}</li>
    </div>
  `
})
class DropDown{
  @Input('initial-state') isOpened;
  @Input() items;
  toggle(newState){
    this.isOpened = newState !== undefined ? newState: !this.isOpened:
  }
}
```

then from parent component:

```
<input (blur)="dropdown.toggle(false)" [(ngModel)]="searchText"  (click)="dropdown.toggle(true)">
<dropdown #dropdown [initial-state]="true" [items]="items"></dropdown>
```

You can also load the component via [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) to avoid the `*ngIf`. But if anything, it'll make the code messier.